# Reverse percentage calculation

Tags: math, logic

I have below 5 items with percentage

```
 P1 = 10%
 P2 = 30%
 P3 = 50%
 P4 = 60%
 P5 = 10%
 Total = 160%
 Actual Percentage = 1.6 (160/100)
```

Now suppose i want to decrease percentage lets say by 0.6, so actual percentage value will be 1.
But How much i should decrease the percentage from all products? so that my Final Total will be 100%.

Is there any reverse percentage calculation generic formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you don't call that as 160% but instead, 1.6 portion counts for 100%.
updated percentages:

P1 = (10/160) * 100 = 6.25%

P2 = 18.75%

P3 = 31.25%

P4 = 37.5%

P5 = 6.25%

Now no matter how much value you decrease from total, if you decrease it proportionally from every item, the perscentages should remain the same.

Percentage actually denotes portion of total.